# how to translate like button in unsupported locale (i.e. en_CA)

Tags: internationalization, facebook-like

I've understood from [like button doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)  and [i18n](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/) that I can replace en_US with a subset of the standard locale ([xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639)_[YY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)):

http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1

But I cannot use the server-side locale straightforward because fb's list is incomplete.

How can I determine the correct mapping for the missing locale? 
As an example en_CA and fr_BE are missing from the "*[official fb locale list](http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)*"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I've found is using the resource bundle through:

```
<spring:message code="fb.locale" text="${locale }" var="fb_locale"/>
<c:out value="&lt;script" escapeXml="false"></c:out> src="http://connect.facebook.net/${fb_locale}/all.js#xfbml=1"<c:out value="&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
    <span style="position: relative; top: 20px; left: 0px;">
        <c:out value="&lt;fb:like" escapeXml="false"></c:out> href="${facebook_i_like_url}" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="90" font="trebuchet ms"<c:out value="&gt;&lt;/fb:
like&gt;" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
    </span>
```

in this way all the "exceptions" can be described in the message_xx_YY.properties files